# c++ reference to non existing map value: segmentation fault

Tags: c++, reference, stdmap

Suppose I have

```
std::map<int, std::vector<double>> a;
```

is this legal?

```
std::vector<double>& b = a[n];
```

where `n` is a non-existing key.
I would say yes, in some simplified version works but in the actual program I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Your sample is valid, unless the lifetime of the map is shorter than the lifetime of the vector

Comment: `a` is the member of a class while `b` is defined in a method.

Comment: we need a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is legal.

When you use the `operator[]` function on a map, an item is inserted if it is not there.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.

Comment: Do you have any idea of where this segmentation fault may come from? (`a` is a member of a class)

Answer (score 1):

`map::operator[]` will perform a lookup of the key, and return the associated value if found.

If not found, the key will be inserted with a default-initialized value.

So what you wrote should be perfectly legal.

see 23.4.4.3 :

> **map element access** [map.access]
>   `T& operator[](const key_type& x);` 
>   1) Effects: If there is no key equivalent to x in the map, inserts value_type(x, T()) into the map